# Ubuntu Software app won't open (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Tags: 16.04, launcher

Following a recent OS update a few days back (16.04 LTS), when I click on the icon labelled "Ubuntu Software" (which is directly below the Dash icon and looks like an orange briefcase with a white A on it), it no longer opens. It used to open fine, but since the update has stopped working. I get no error message. All I get is that circular progress thingy (does it have an official name?) for about 15 secs, then it disappears and the app doesn't open.
How do I go about diagnosing what the issue is and/or reinstall the app?
Thank you.

ParanoidPanda:
I opened a terminal, typed gnome-software and on a new line I got a flashing white block cursor for a while, then it stopped flashing. I wasn't returned to a prompt with a $ symbol. The terminal appeared to have frozen so I clicked on the x to close it.
Edit: I tried again and waited a minute or so this time, but same result, so clicked on x

Comment: Please launch it by opening Terminal (CTRL + ALT + T), typing `gnome-software`, and pressing ENTER. Then [edit] your question with the output it gives you.

Comment: You will know if it has exited because Terminal will give you back the line with the `$` if and when that is the case.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the title.

Answer (score 0):

You have a glitch in your configuration.  Remove or rename your `~/.local/share/gnome-software` folder.

Run these commands:

```
$ killall gnome-software
$ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software
```

Comment: A glitch? I never saw a black cat.OK ran those commands, but now what?

Comment: @Anonymous.User I'm confused about the black cat?  Can you elaborate?  My reference to glitch is in reference to some change or discrepancy of a configuration that has happen without the user's input.

Comment: It's a Matrix reference - see http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/D%C3%A9j%C3%A0_vu and search for "cat". Anyway, after restarting Ubuntu Software is working again, so thanks very much for your help.

Comment: I'm a noob (if it's not already obvious) - could you tell me please what rm -r ~ mean/do?

Comment: @Anonymous.User It removes the named directory recursively.  Meaning all the files and directories in it.

Comment: Umm, I'm going to need the 5-year-old explanation please. I mean I just Googled "recursively" and got this: "Relating to or involving a program or routine of which a part requires the application of the whole, so that its explicit interpretation requires in general many successive executions." I'm none the wiser. Could you explain in baby-speak please? Also, what does the tilde (~) do? And is there meant to be a space between the forward slash and .local? Is the space optional or does it have to be there? Could you refer me to a site that explains all this in a way that noobs can understand?

Comment: The tilde is a symbol representing the user's home directory.  I understand that you are a novice.  I don't think I could actually teach the details to a baby.  But I'm hoping that you will copy and paste the command to your terminal so that you will have the spaces and letters exact.  After you paste the command to the terminal, the problem you're having with `Ubuntu-Software` will be gone.

Comment: Yeah, the problem disappeared (as I mentioned above), but I had to restart my computer before it disappeared. Re pasting into the terminal, I'd always tried Ctrl + V before realizing that right-click/Paste worked, and also Edit/Paste.

Comment: @Anonymous.User Thanks for acknowledging that the process worked.  Glad to have been of assistance.  Enjoy Ubuntu!  Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was actually installing it - I would click on the icon in the nav bar or via the dashboard, and it would appear to start, then close after appx. 3 sec.

I tried starting it from the terminal, same thing. Then I tried updating the app - wasn't found. So I installed via the typical 'sudo apt get' and it starts just fine now :-)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about which package you installed via `apt-get`. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)